# Pytest cov does not read pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, pytest-cov, pyproject.toml

Pytest cov is not reading its setting from the pyproject.toml file. I am using nox, so I run the test with:

```
python3 -m nox
```

It seems I have the same issue even without nox.

In fact, after running a `poetry install`:

- `poetry run pytest --cov=src` passes the test
- `poetry run pytest --cov` does not pass the test

In particular, when failing the test I have the following output (output is cut to the most important stuff):

```
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

/Users/matteo/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-Nz69kfmJ-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py:271: PytestWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

  self.cov_controller.finish()


---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.7.7-final-0 -----------

FAIL Required test coverage of 100.0% not reached. Total coverage: 0.00%
```

[Code with a reproducible error here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDELfowePPT2FFGaAeNhYErrHPL3GMmy/view?usp=sharing).
To run it you'll need to [install poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) and to [install nox](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/).

Comment: What exactly doesn't pass the test? You have added the same command twice.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Fix it above

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the `src` layout wrong. The meaning of the `src` dir is to avoid accidental imports of the code from repository, ensuring the package is always installed. `poetry` supports `src` layout; in your case, you'd have to add `packages = [{ include = 'project', from = 'src' }]` to the `tool.poetry` section and `source = ['project']` to `tool.coverage.run`.

Comment: Or you can drop the `src` dir completely if you don't need the `src` layout. Anyway, `from src.project import code` should be fixed. Your root package is `project`, not `src`.

Comment: That's an important lesson, thank you. I see that just changing the import solves the problem. If you want to write it as an answer I will accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer:

Check the current treatment of the `src` directory. Right now, it seems to be a namespace package which is not what you intend. Either switch to the `src` layout:

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [
    { include = 'project', from = 'src' }
]

[tool.coverage.run]
...
source = ['project']
```

and fix the import in `test_code.py`:

```
from src.project import code
```

to

```
from project import code
```

or remove the `src` dir:

```
rootdir
├── project
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_code.py
```

and fix the import in `test_code.py`.